# WCF Client Not working when outside solution

Tags: c#, wcf

I have created a WCF service hosted in a windows service.

Basically all the service does is that it gets data from the database, does some work in memory with it and save data back to the database.

i created a windows form client to consume the service.
Inside the solution of the service, i added a service reference to the service in the project and everything works fine, however when i installed the service and run it, i created a separate client project and referenced the hosted service.

When i call the function that does the work, it doesn't work. (it must update a flag in the database)

Can you please suggest what may be causing this problem, i have not posted any code example because the code is too big, mainly it uses ado.net, Nhibernate ...

Comment: Have you got any logging going on?  If not, then do put it in.  When you say not working what do you mean?  Do you get any output or an error message?

Comment: Are you getting any error? Can you debug the code?

Comment: `i created a separate client project and referenced the hosted service` what do you mean by that? From client you need to connect to wcf service, not add reference.

Comment: @Kangkan, i am new to services, i am finding it pretty hard to debug it when i call it from outside the solution.

Comment: @Reniuz, my wcf is hosted in a windows service, explain more if i am mistaken please !

Comment: Can you show your code and write steps what you are doing?

Comment: @SirajMansour: Please share what exactly goes wrong when you call the service. Have you configured the service ports etc? Are you running both the service and client in the same machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
The configuration of my WCF has to be placed in the configuration file of the host, which is a windows service in my case.

Answer (score 1):

If the service is in another project it is likely not running when the second project attempts to access it.

Either setup IIS to expose the service (this is normally how a production environment would be setup) or as a test, use the IIS Light (Cassini) that is provided with Visual Studio to host the service.

Once either of the choices above have been implemented, configure the client to use the service - the URL likely changed.

Comment: He is self hosting the service, not hosting in IIS. This is routine in WCF, especially when not exposing end points using HTTP as the transport mechanism.

Comment: @PrestonGuillot - OK - good point +1 - my bad for assuming, and not reading the question clearly enough...